# Rendering after interpolating, renders inside/outside other objects

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution, interpolation, lerp

So, we're working out our interpolated render-coordinates during our render call and it's doing a fantastic job of smoothing everything out.  All is great and collision detection is working to a perfectly acceptable level (for simple CD - ie, player hits other object, looses a life, starts over...).

However, how do we deal with situations that require 'collision and resolution'?  The classic example, of course, being our player character colliding with a solid object (usually a platform or the ground) and then being 'resolved' to bring the 2 entities out of collision.... here is what I mean:

[image]

Even if we say something simple like 'just don't interpolate vertically when touching a platform' - that wouldn't seem a very clean solution because we need to think about slopes where the player is moving both left/right as well as up/down.

What is the easiest and cleanest way to protect ourselves from this happening?

Comment: If you already have the infrastructure to make exceptions for the interpolation part, why not "don't interpolate when a collision resolution has taken place"?

Comment: Well @PandaPajama lets take my slope example. The whole point of doing the interpolation is to keep my sprite movement smooth. So lets say I'm walking up or down a slope (or sliding down a slope) Now, during this action we wont be interpolating, therefore, the sprite would be subject to choppiness as we wont be interpolating it (as character would be in collision with the slope), which defeats the whole point of introducing interpolation in the first place if you see what I mean.

Comment: Actually I don't. I don't understand the reasoning behind interpolating the rendering. In any case, when interpolating, you will always have incomplete information, and therefore will have cases in which your interpolated results won't match what's happening in the world.

Comment: I still don't understand why you think an interpolated rendering will have better chance of making it to the vSync deadline than a non-interpolated rendering, and how can you know that -before- you begin rendering (so you can choose whether or not to interpolate). Sorry to give a different opinion, but if you're having trouble with dropped frames, and no dropped frames is a requirement of your game, then you should work on fixing that instead of trying to make solutions that will probably just make the problem worse.

Comment: I imagine interpolated rendering makes sense when your -physics- code cannot run at the same speed as the rendering code, so you have to figure out where the objects are even if you don't have a solution from the physics part yet. That doesn't seem to be your case though...

Comment: I get you but its not that simple, I run my code on my dev device at 60fps all is great no dropped frames. I need to make sure it runs well and looks great on the thousands of other Android devices out there, a lot of which won't be able to handle this without A) slowing down or B) discarding rendering frames to keep the simulation running at the same speed. Option A) isn't for me and option B) causes choppiness which is why I am interpolating. My loop has logic capped at 60 ticks per second and renders as fast as the device can handle.

Comment: However my reasons for implementing interpolation are irrelevant. The question is valid and still stands :-)

Comment: No, I think it's an interesting question, and that's why I upvoted it. But I still think your approach is incorrect and is better served by an improved gameloop instead. The amount of time rendering takes is proportional to the amount of stuff you will draw, and since you're drawing the same stuff with or without interpolation, your graphics code won't run faster because the positions of your objects are interpolated. You won't get better performance with interpolation (if I understand what you're doing correctly).

Comment: Ah no, I agree, performance won't be better that's for sure, however 'perceived' performance ***is*** better, if I run my interpolated game next to my non-interpolated game, the difference is startling:-) unfortunately I can't envisage a gameloop that will run perfectly on every device out there without using some form of interpolation / visual correction. That being said I would like to hear your thoughts on my game loop(s) implementation - I will post a question at some point and comment here so you can take a look :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics engine should not report the player's position within the platform.  Collision detection and resolution are both part of a single physics simulation time step.

Your rendering lerp function will not have this this problem if it is correct.  Again, this is because the physics engine should have resolved the player's correct position after collision detection, all before the render logic takes over.

Comment: Hi @WilliamMorrison, thanks for the answer. However, as you can see from my diagram, my logic *is* resolving collision (steps 1 & 2) within one logic update, so, when it gets to render(), the object *is* reported as sitting nicely on the platform (not in it).  However, the lerp function would then alter the object position for rendering purposes.  This is where it gets rendered.  Would it help if I posted the code I'm using to interpolate between old and current positions? Or maybe you could expand you answer to with a diagram or example to show what you mean if I've misunderstood.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the lerp function might help, I don't expect to see problems there though as its simple. Is the player being rendered hovering above the platform when the player is at a rest?

Comment: You're absolutely right @WilliamMorrison, I've been over my code and I've realised that there was indeed a problem.  The problem now *should* be resolved.  It was an issue with previous and current positions.  Now though lerping, effectively stops when the player hits a platform.  The first time, lerp will do it's thing, but on subsequent occasions, the difference between the old and new position will be 0 so no lerping happens!! Thanks!

Comment: There still, however, remains the issue of lerping a player going up or down a slope - as far as I can tell, the same logic can't be applied in cases like these because the player is moving left/right ***and*** up/down, so the lerping will never 'stop' - in these situations, my character is actually being rendered **above** or slightly embedded **in**  the slope tiles.  However, I will say that for this question, the basic problem for horizontal or vertical collision has been resolved.  I'll open another question for sloping and will link it from here if you could take a look - thanks

Comment: @user22241 Yeah, sure thing.  Glad you figured it out!  Interested to see the next question.

Comment: Hi @WilliamMorrison, OK I've asked another question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83650/lerping-character-moving-up-and-down-slope-tiles if you have any suggestions, that would be great.  I can't work out how to get it working - thanks!

Comment: @user22241 I've replied.  Hopefully it clears everything up here.  I think you've done all you should do with this problem.  See answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The case of your problem is that the time of collision (as know as time of impact, TOI) does not match the time of current neither next frame. In fact, any collision potentially can happen between two render frames. All you can do is only to cheat and pass not a real time, but a TOI to your lerp function.